# Default route for .NetCore WebAPI if all other routes fail

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-webapi, endpoint

I am making a .NetCore WebAPI in Service Fabric and I want to have a default endpoint. If the call doesn't match a defined route, the call should go to the default route and I can perform my work for all other routes.

e.g 
My Defined Endpoints

```
api/Values/5 => return 5
api/Values => return {5,10}
```

For all other endpoints,

```
api/.../...  => return Default value;
controller/...=> return Default value;
.../.../... => return Default value;
```

Comment: So what have you tried and what exactly your problem is? There is a pretty good [documentation about routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Comment: I am using Reverse Proxy in Service Fabric, the issue is if the Reverse Proxy doesn't find a defined endpoint, it keeps on re-polling the service thinking the service or node might be down until the request times out. So if I try any endpoint that is not defined, it will take 120 seconds. What I want is that if the endpoint is not defined, it should route to a default endpoint where I could return an error. And rather than defining explicitly 5-10 endpoints, I have a single endpoint where I return the error.